# How open the context menu on page refresh button in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, developer-tools

In this [video](http://monosnap.com/file/tfEwFCPIywaWuM83A3V89rN8L3VkO1) at 1:07 the user click somehow the refresh button and a context menu pops up containing the following options:

- Normal reload
- Hard reload
- Empty cache and Hard reload

How did he do that? I couldn't find any <kbd>key</kbd> + click combo to open that menu. I have tried the followings:

- <kbd>⌘</kbd> + click
- <kbd>option</kbd> + click
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + click
- <kbd>shift</kbd> + click

A picture showing a frame from the video:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see answer here: [Chrome browser reload options new feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633425/chrome-browser-reload-options-new-feature)

Requires developer tools to be open.